# How to avoid unused variables with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is a good JavaScript technique/convention/standard to avoid `unused variables`?

For example, if I'm calling a function like below and I just want to use the 3rd parameter, what do I do with the 1st and 2nd parameters?

```
$.ajax({
    success: function(first, second, third){
        console.log("just using: " + third);
    }
});
```

Comment: You do nothing, this is the way it's done. You could use `arguments`, but why ?

Comment: Yes but, for example in LUA you could do something like `success: function(_,_,third)`

Comment: In strict mode you will get an exception: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Strict mode function may not have duplicate parameter names`

Comment: Yes, you're right: I meant function(1underscore,2underscores,third)

Comment: You can do the same in javascript `function(_, __, third)` as the underscore is a valid name, but it's still the exact same thing, you just gave the arguments a different name.

Comment: small update, eslint has a rule "no-unused-vars" which is quite annoying on ajax and forEach. you could `// eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars` but I get the reasoning. @vlad-nikitin's answer gets the job done with purpose, but it doesn't disarm the error! still looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignore them.

(You *could* define your function as `function () {` and then use `var third = arguments[2];` but that doesn't lend itself to very readable code).

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you, and yes, that doesn't make the code readable at all.

Answer (score 2):

this `first, second` params if they have no references will be deleted by Garbage collector, to help him to do it you can make next in the start of your function

```
success: function(first, second, third){
first = second = null;
......
```